# Jquery click code being called multiple times

Tags: jquery, click

I tried adding my code into a fiddle and it works fine in there so please, try to analyze it straight on my site.
Here is the page: http://cacharro.ole32.com/shopping/

if you go to groceries.js, at line 39 there is the code for the clic event on the #addNewSection image.

then in the page you click in the big gree + buton, a formulary will pop up, and click again in the big green + symbol. You'll notice that the code inside the .click() function is called more than once..

does anyone knows why ??

EDIT:

I found the source of my error. Y added the hooking to the event in a function called init, something like:

```
function init() {
     $("#addNewSection").click( function(e){
          newSectionButtonClicked();
     });
}
```

and added a call in the `$(function() ....` BUT I also call this init() from other sites so everytime I call it a new instance of the function is hooked to the click event!! Is there a way to hook on the event only if we are not hooked already????

Comment: can you share the click event code.

Comment: @javirs pls check my code

Comment: for doing action only once you can use boolean variable var isInitialize = false; and check it function init(){ if (isInitialize) return; isInitialize = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call init() function only 1 time, or remove the assignment of click event inside this function and put in in a function that will be called only one time, for example:

```
$("#addNewSection").click( function(e){
  newSectionButtonClicked();
});
```

this function is called every time you call the init() function, so this event will be trigged one more time for every init() you call.

You should call this registration only one time

Comment: That was my first guess as well, but using a breakpoint shows that the init() is run just once

Comment: i've put a lot of breakpoint and i pass through init() more times, i'll check again

Comment: this is definitelly what Im doing .. init is called more than once. and the hooking is done more than once. Is there a way to check if we are already hooked ??? I will clean up my code to hook in a differente function but .. is there a way to check that ??

Comment: or.. is there a way to delete the old hooks ??

Comment: with $('#NAME').off('click'); you can remove the old handler

Answer (score 1):

Is your code registering the click handler more than one time on the same element. If so try to check the code. This is the situation which i have also faced. for first time click called once, for second time twice and so on every click register an a click handler on the same handler.

Also if you can show us the code for review.

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawMarket(){
    $("#market").html("<ul id='marketList'>");
    $.each(sections, function(idx, obj){
        var name = htmlDecode(obj.Name);
        var listItem = $('<li  />');
        listItem.append(name);
        var innerComponent = $("<ul class='section' id='S_"+obj.Id+"'/>");

            var ItemName = htmlDecode(ItemObj.Name);
            innerComponent.append("<li id='"+ItemObj.Id+"' class='item'>"+ItemName+"</li>");

        listItem.append(innerComponent);
        listItem.append("<div class='clearer'/>");
        $("#marketList").append(listItem);
    });
    init();
}
```

Please replace this function inside your ***groceries.js***  it will help you

You don't need to each loop inside this function because it will always append inner text

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it... I have sections and every section has items. The outer each loops for every section. and for every section I want to add every item it contains. There is no way to avoid the inner loop.

Comment: can you try this once and see results

Comment: ItemObj will be unknown .. isnt it ?

Comment: yes I did and, as expected, ItemObj is NULL, never filled with nothing, ItemObj.Name is unknown, `Uncaught ReferenceError: ItemObj is not defined `

Answer (score 0):

You call function drawMarket() in the newSectionButtonClicked() each time when you click on the plus button, and call init() function in the drawMarket(), so you define click event many times

You can do something like this for make only one initial definithion:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addNewSection").click( function(e){
        newSectionButtonClicked();
    });
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});
```